# Access css styles of angular 2 component

Tags: angular

I want to write a service which parses css code and does some stuff with that information. So I need access to the computed css code of a component within that component (from both *styles* and *styleUrls*) to give it to the service.

With the RootRenderer from @angular/core I could access the css code of all components but I would need to have the generated host name (e.g. *_nghost-lew-1*). Of course I would prefer a cleaner solution. Do you know any way or do I need to fill a feature request?

Comment: Could you be a bit clearer about what you're trying to achieve? What is this "service" going to do, and when in the lifecycle is it applied (e.g. dev, build, run).

Comment: I need the css code at runtime within the components constructor or ngOnInit(). I want to give the stylesheets to the service which will cache them for each unique component. The service should detect some special selectors and give back that information.

Comment: To what end, though?

Comment: I want to create element queries (like https://github.com/marcj/css-element-queries). This package analyzes all css code, but I just need it for some components. I don't want to have the query information in my typescript code.